# Use System.Net.WebSockets.Client of .net7 in .Net Framework

Tags: c#, websocket, nuget

I'm using .Net Framework 4.8 to connect via a ClientWebSocket to a vendor.
Unfortunately the vendor changed sth on his system resulting every connection in a handshake error (426 Upgrade Required).

I did some tests and found out that running the same code in .Net 7 still works.
Migrating the whole project is currently not a solution.

Microsoft offers a System.Net.WebSockets.Client Nuget package that can be installed in .NetFramework as well. Is it possible to use the ClientWebSocket class from the Nuget package rather than the built-in one? If so, how? They both share the same namespace.

Comment: The same issue here. Any workarounds ?

Comment: @EldarZeynalov Unfortunately no soution so far. In my case the vendor rolled back the changes caused by an incompatible library on his side. If it comes to worst you might take .Net 7 source code for websocket and change the namespace when including it to your project. But that normally requires many additional dependencies to be handled as well...